# How to perform a text-search on a List of CustomObjects that includes the search misspelled words?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to perform a text-search on entry of my custom class. That text-search should not only match for the string entered, but may also check for misspelled words. So I'm looking for a library that does that for me.

A little bit more context:
Let's say I generate this business object from an SQLServer2008 database:

```
public class MyTextObject
{
  public String Title {get;set;}
  public String Content {get;set;}
}
```

In my application I'd have a

```
List<MyTextObject>
```

and want to perform a search for the word "control". The search should return any MyTextObject that has the word "control" inside the Title or Content property. So far no problem: I could easily do this with a LINQ-Expression.

Here is the tricky part:
Let's say in one of my business objects, I wanted to write "control" but I've written "contrlo" instead. I want that the search algorithm suggests that business object as well.
How can I do that in a non brute-force way that looks for possible permutations of the search key? Is there any algorithm or library out there that might help me with this situation?
I'm also open to other good suggestions =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you need some fuzzy like string matching algorithm. I have done something similar a while ago, I used Levenshtein Distance, and I believe [this is the code that I ripped off](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein). I was quite satisfied.

Comment: Ok I understand what the levenshtein Distance is. Yet I don't see how is can be possible to create word with the distance without brute force. (The reason for this statement: the levenshtein distance is not a injective function (seen as a mathematical function))

Comment: @citronas If by brute-force you mean looping through collection of strings and matching with the misspelled word then yeah, I don't think there can be other way around that. You will have to either bruteforce and fuzzy match against some dictionary to correct the spelling and then try to match against your object, or try to fuzzy match against each (some?) words in your object. Or find a ready to go solution :D If you are looking for magic library you might want to check out lucene.net

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a simple idea that we have follow.

First we search for the word that les say is the "contrlo".
**If this word not found, we make an automatic correction** on spelling that give us the word "control" (and maybe some more) and now we search for the corrected word.

There are a lot of spelling corrections that you can find.

### Other Suggestion

I suggest to use the [dtSearch](http://www.dtsearch.com/). Its commercial but I say that is worth it. They give a simple dll that can do a real search with many parametres.

Comment: @Aritos: I also thought of that, but what if I have 3 results for "control" and "contrlo" would be 8 other?

Comment: @citronas well, if your result must be unique (only 1 result), then use one more function to decide what word is closer to the one you look

Comment: @citronas You search for the contrlo, logically you not find it, then you make spell check, and you get the word control, and you search again. If you find more than one corrected word then select the one that is closer base on an algorithm like the one m0s propose. But you can not start with m0s propose, because you do not know what is the correct word from the beginning...